# leaflet R png overlay

Tags: r, leaflet, png

I am looking for the equivalent of png map overlays - that are possible both in kml (e.g. maptools::kmlOverlay) as well as in the javascript version of leaflet - in the R leaflet library. 
Adding a raster image is not quite what I am looking for; instead I am starting with georeferenced png images.
Is this easily achieved ?

Comment: As long as you convert your png to a raster brick you can use `mapview::viewRGB`to view it. See `?mapview::viewRGB` for an example with a standard jpg.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/timelyportfolio/8f6c8cc27597466351ad377e6774c30f this link shows you how to impliment regular leaflet functions into R...so you can create it yourself.

Comment: Thanks so much for both answers

Comment: @MarkusLoecher if you were able to answer your own question, would you mind posting a solution?

Comment: Very sorry but I do not have a working solution yet